# Segfault on glNamedBufferStorage

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently reading the OpenGL Super Bible 7th edition. Based on that, I wrote some simple code like this:

```
void startup() {
    static const float data[] = {
        0.25f, -0.25f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
        0.25f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
    };


    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    printf("Size of data[]: %lu bytes\n", sizeof(data));
    glNamedBufferStorage(m_VBO, sizeof(data), data, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

}
```

This is a method of a class that is run before the main rendering loop.

The problem is that this code generates a segfault at `glNamedBufferStorage`.

I tried debugging it with gdb - and learned only where the segfault occurs, not why. I tried to understand if there is a problem with `data`'s size (hence the `printf sizeof`). But it seems to be ok. I also tried to use different flags - also to no avail.

I also did a `grep -R` on the accompanying source code, but found no usage examples.

System: Ubuntu, clang++

Comment: What [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) are you using? Does your implementation support OpenGL 4.5?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm using the example framework from the book, which in turn uses gl3w + glfw - and it seems to work fine - the examples compile and run correctly and some of my earlier examples (without trying to create a VBO) also worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your OpenGL version with

`printf("OpenGL version %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));`

glNamedBufferStorage supported only on OpenGL 4.5

Comment: You are right! I was actually upgrading the driver when I posted this question. Seems like my older driver supported only up to 4.4 (I felt certain it supports 4.5 too!) and the new one has 4.5. Now glNamedBufferStorage is working correctly.